# Convert NumPy arrays to Pandas Dataframe with columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to normalize my both categorical and numeric values.

```
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
df_num = df.drop(CAT_COLUMNS, axis=1)
df_num = df_num.as_matrix()
df_num = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_num)

df.fillna('NA', inplace=True)
df_cat = df.T.to_dict().values()

vec_cat = DictVectorizer( sparse=False )
df_cat = vec_cat.fit_transform(df_cat)
```

After that I need to combine 2 `numpy` arrays back to `pandas` dataframe, but below approach doesn't work for me.

```
mas = np.hstack((df_num, df_cat))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mas, columns=cols)
```

**Error Message:** `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (475, 243), indices imply (83, 243)`

> One more approach:

```
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
for col in columns:
    try:
        if col in CAT_COLUMNS:
            df[col] = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
        else:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit)
    except Exception, err:
        print 'Column: %s and msg=%s' % (col, err.message)
```

**Error Message:**

`Column: DATE and msg=Singleton array array(1444424400.0) cannot be considered a valid collection.
Column: QTR_HR_START and msg=Singleton array array(21600000L, dtype=int64) cannot be considered a valid collection.
...`

> PS. Is there any way to avoid numpy et all? As example, I want to leverage on `pandas_ml` library

Comment: doesn't work does not explain why it failed. Why doesn't it work? it gives an error or it doesn't give the expected output?

Comment: I added an example of how to do this pure pandas. Although, if your goal is machine learning, it might be better to go the pure numpy route and not convert back to pandas.

Comment: Agree, but I am investigating very convenient library `pandas_ml`, and here all calculations based on pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about pretty simple following approach?

```
def normalize_dataframe(df):
    columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
    for col in columns:
        try:
            if col in CAT_COLUMNS:
                df[col] = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
            else:
                df[col] = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[col])
        except Exception, err:
            print 'Column: %s and msg=%s' % (col, err.message)
    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are  looking for is [`pandas.get_dummies()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html). It will perform one hot encoding on categorical columns, and produce a dataframe as the result. From there you can use `pandas.concat([existing_df, new_df],axis=0)` to add the new columns to your existing dataframe. This will avoid the use of a numpy array.

An example of how it could be used:

```
for cat_column in CAT_COLUMNS:
    dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(df[column])

    #Optionally rename columns to indicate categorical feature name
    dummy_df.columns = ["%s_%s" % (cat_column, col) for col in dummy_df.columns]
    df = pd.concat([df, dummy_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Any advice about: 

1. how correctly replace categorical columns? 2 how normalize numeric columns in this case properly?